# After I upgraded teamcity to 2017.2.2 I get 404 errors

Tags: teamcity

The service is running but I get a half corrupted page. I upgraded using the automatic update mechanism. Note that the teamcity is running behind an nginx server with the real service running at http://$hostname:8080/teamcity and nginx forwarding from http://$hostname/teamcity.

[image]

If I restart the service I get the following log in **teamcity-server.log**

https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/74ea8fa9c422c51a23820ee74cab72cc

linked as gist as SO will not allow pasting such a large file in.

Answer (score 0):

Switch it off / switch it on. It works again. ( No idea why )